# $\tan(\alpha)=\alpha$ has not complex roots?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, roots

By the Strum theory it is easy to see that the equation $\tan(\alpha)=\alpha$ has not complex roots and it's real roots occur at zero and near $(2n+1)\pi/2,\ n\in Z^{+}$.  I am interesting to know that is there any other way to see that the above equation has not complex roots?

Comment: $0$ is a complex root :~).

Comment: I mean a pure complex root ( $a+ib$ with $b\neq 0 $)

Comment: A very interesting question! Could you rephrase similarly to :  " in every interval $((2n-1)\pi/2, (2n+1)\pi/2)$ the equation has exactly one real root. Show there are no other complex roots" . Also, you don't need Sturm theory to locate the real roots.

Comment: By 'Sturm theory" are you referring to an argument like the one in [this answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/248369/5531) which shows that all roots of $\tan z = z$ are real by using the fact that they are precisely the zeros of $\left(\frac{\sin z}{z}\right)'$?

Comment: Your answer is intersting, but by  'Sturm theory' I am  referring to the work by R. P. Agarwal: http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387712758 --Lecture (36).

Comment: @Albert: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246841/can-the-real-and-imaginary-parts-of-dfrac-sin-zz-be-simplified) contains an elementary proof.